# arrange my menus and submenus on mobile when the submenu don't not show

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

hello dear all I work on a project in angular 15. I recover menus, categories, types and subtypes from the database. this one is displayed very well on desktop but on mobile when I scroll down the menu it scrolls down but when I scroll down the category to see the types I have an error. thank you for your help

I entered my menus in a static way and it works very well

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown" *ngFor="let menu of menus" >
                  <a data-bs-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle{{ menu.id === 1 ?' active':''}}" href="#">{{menu.name}}</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="let category of menu.categories">
                          <a class="dropdown-item menu-link dropdown-toggler" href="#">{{category.name}}</a>
                          <div class="dropdown-menu">
                              <ul  *ngFor="let type of category.types">
                                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" class="dropdown-item nav-link{{ type.sub_types.length > 0 ? ' dropdown-toggler' : '' }}"  (click)="onMenuClick(menu,category,type)">{{type.name}}</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <ul *ngFor="let subtype of type.sub_types">
                                        <li>
                                          <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="dropdown-item nav-link nav_item"   (click)="onMenuClick1(menu,category,type,subtype)">{{subtype.name}}</a>
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  </li>

                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </li>


                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </li>




        <li >
          <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">A Propos</a>

      </li>
          </ul>
```

```
onMenuClick(menu:Menu,category:Category,type:Type) {
    const MenuSlug = menu.slug;
    const categorieslug = category.slug;
    const slug = type.slug;
    this.router.navigate([`/${MenuSlug}`], { queryParams: { "category": categorieslug, "types": slug} });
  }
  onMenuClick1(menu:Menu,category:Category,type:Type,subtype:SubType) {
    const MenuSlug = menu.slug;
    const categorieslug = category.slug;
    const slug = type.slug;
    const subtypeSlug = subtype.slug
    this.router.navigate([`/${MenuSlug}`], { queryParams: { "category": categorieslug, "types": slug ,"subtype":subtypeSlug} });
  }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which errors are you facing? Also, how does your menu object looks like?

Comment: yes sir, in fact if you take a good look at my code you will see that I have: menu, categories, types, subtypes. when my site is displayed on mobile, and I click on menu, this one goes well but when I click on categories to expand the types nothing happens